# i'm using django custom backend check JWTtoken has error: userprofile matching query not existing?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i'm use djang rest framework JWTtoken has error: userprofile matching query not existing, i check code and not found the error is where.

[image]

[image]

after debug is get the msg:

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Unable to login with the authentication information provided。"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `get` operator. It does raise error if the query is not found.
By looking at query you are trying to get user with `username=username` or `password=password` that it's matches the `password` provided in request.

This error is because there is no user with that credentials in database. nothing more.

Comment: when i try post data to http://127.0.0.1:8000/login with JWTToken, always return "Unable to login with the authentication information provided", look at:
https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/issues/461

Comment: are you sure credentials are right? or maybe you are not passing the right jwt token. is it in the right format? is prefix ok? can you debug djagno and capture request.headers and see how Authorization header is captured?

Comment: when i try post data to http://127.0.0.1:8000/login with JWTToken, always return "Unable to login with the authentication information provided", look at:
https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/issues/461. or i should create username use "createsuperuser", then post data to database? thanks!

Comment: how exactly did you created your users? remember always use `User.objects.create_user()` method or after creating user set password with `user.set_password('my password')`.